# Prevent Twig from inserting line break after {% include %}

Tags: php, twig, newline, whitespace

Twig seems to insert a `\n` after the content of an `{% include %}`. I can reproduce the problem with this simple example:

test.php:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, []);

echo $twig->render('test.twig', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

test.twig:

```
{% include "include.twig" %}{{ foo }}
```

include.twig:

```
Foo:
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
Foo:bar
```

but instead it is:

```
Foo:
bar
```

Is there a way I can prevent this? Twig's whitespace control with `{%- ... -%}` does not affect this.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in sjagr's answer, there is in fact an extra `0x0a` character at the end of the template that's not shown in VIM even with `:set binary`.

Know I know why this happens but I still need a solution. Inspecting all templates with a hex editor is not a viable option.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your `include.twig` file contains a return character at the end of `Foo:`?

Comment: When I use `:set list` and `:set binary` in VIM to show all whitespace, the file is displayed as "Foo:$", no extra characters.

Comment: My answer may provide some better clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text editor is appending a newline character at the end of your `.twig` files.

I can reproduce your issue described in the question when I'm working with regular text editors, or `nano`. A hex sum of the `include.twig` file shows the newline:

```
$ xxd -p include.twig
466f6f3a0a
```

To prove that the text editors are inserting these newline characters, I removed the `include.twig` file and made a `generate.php` file:

```
file_put_contents('include.twig', 'Foo:');
```

New hex sum:

```
$ xxd -p include.twig
466f6f3a
```

And new Twig output:

```
Foo:bar
```

Try for yourself!

Interestingly, you can have Twig ignore the trailing newline when including template files by adding a blank comment to the end of the file:

```
Foo:{# #}
```

Comment: Ok, that explains why this happens. Thanks. But I still need a solution. I can't create all my Twig templates this way.

Comment: @lnwdr I found [one discussion about the matter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2082845) - unfortunately Drupal devs just dismissed the idea as it was a trivial problem. Still digging though I may not find anything else... My edit could be a workaround?